# using AWK for Lookup Table and Replace first column of 1st file with another column of 2nd file

Tags: awk, lookup

I am trying to use AWK Command in shell for lookup table to replace coloumn with another column value matching the first file.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1,a[$2]=$2;next}{print a{$1],a[$2]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

I am not getting any success. Please Help me with AWK Command Syntax that would give me desired output results.

File1.txt

```
VALUE_TCP21:Z9E1AG.PNT          ABC1        SILVER
VALUE_TCP21:Z9E1CU.PNT          ABC1        COPPER
VALUE_TCP21:Z9E1RH.PNT          ABC1        HUMIDITY
VALUE_TCP21:Z9E1TT001.PNT       ABC1        TEMP
```

File2.txt

```
VALUE_TCP21:Z9E1AG.PNT    3716.09
VALUE_TCP21:Z9E1CU.PNT    4015.55
VALUE_TCP21:Z9E1RH.PNT    54.4023
VALUE_TCP21:Z9E1TT001.PNT 24.9414
```

Desired Output:

```
 ABC1  SILVER     3716.09
 ABC1  COPPER     4015.55
 ABC1  HUMIDITY   54.4023
 ABC1  TEMP       24.9414
```

Comment: What should be printed when a $1 from either file doesn't exist in the other file?

Comment: It will never happen actual i am Mapping Tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 OFS $3;next}{print a[$1],$2}' File1.txt File2.txt | column -t
```

Brief explanation,

- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 OFS $3;next}`: in file1.txt, assign `$1` as the key, and `$2 OFS $3` as the corresponding value in a.
- In File2, just `print a[$1],$2`

Comment: awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2" "$3;next}{print a[$1],$2}' File1.txt File2.txt  this worked